# AngularJS ng-show expression doesnt work on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have Select tag with 2 options and 1 default just saying "Select year". So I want a the div right after the Select to be hidden on load when the option is still on "Select year". The problem is it only hides the div only when I select one of the options then I choose again "Select year".

This is my code:

```
When do you want to study?
<select name="ddlYear" ng-model="data.calendar_year">
    <option value="">-- Select Year --</option>
    <option value"2015" >2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>
<br/>
<div ng-show="data.calendar_year != 0">
<h3>Qualification type:</h3>
</div>
```

So basically on load I need the div containing the  tag to be hidden but I dont know how.

Thank you

Comment: try this.. `<div ng-show="data.calendar_year">`

Comment: It works if I put <div ng-show="!data.calendar_year"> ;) Thank you

Comment: :) I missed the not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the default value for data.calendar_year?
Maybe it equals null or '' so it does !=0.
(if you don't define it before, thats how it is).

Comment: The default value is the first option which is "--Select Year--" @Mort

Comment: oh you are right, when I set it to NULL it works...but not to empty string..Thank you so much

Comment: @beckas Right, the default value here is '', (as somewhat I said). To be exact the default value is the first option value. (for future readers)